# WebAPI PUT and POST go to 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use AJAX to PUT this object to the /api/company/#/:

```
    {"CompanyID":2,"Name":"Test Company","Address1":"","Address2":"","City":"","State":"","Zip":"","ContactName":"","ContactPhone":"","ContactEmail":"","EmployeeCount":"","TypeOfIndustry":"","CompanyRevenue":""}
```

My PUT method:

```
    public void Put (CompanyOverviewView company)
    {
    }
```

CompanyOverviewView:

```
public class CompanyOverviewView {
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string CompanyType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EmployeeCount { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfIndustry { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> CompanyRevenue { get; set; }
```

AJAX Properties:

```
var ajaxProperties = {
        type: "PUT",
    url: "/api/company/5/",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(postdata)
    }
```

I am getting a 404 error, though using the default WebAPI routing. Why would this not hook up? Am I missing something?

Comment: You might want to post your routes just to be clear. Is the controller called `CompanyController` and does it inherit from `ApiController`? Do other actions work?

Comment: I'd highly recommend you try RouteDebugger. So freakin helpful. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx

Comment: Did you check the request to ensure that a PUT/POST request is actually occurring?

Comment: Are you running this on local IIS?

Comment: Use Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) to simulate the `PUT`/`POST` requests using the Composer tab in Fiddler.  Fiddler is a great tool.  Anyways, that would be a good starting point to figuring out the problem.  Secondly, I had this same issue on my local IIS only.  Once deployed to my company's web server, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `processData: false` and `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` to your `ajaxProperties`. This will tell `ajax` to send the request as a JSON body instead of URL parameters.

Comment: How would an incorrectly-formatted request body result in a 404 (unless one is explicitly returned)?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are adding the Id in the URL when you don't need to. Try posting/putting to just /api/company in the ajax. Or alternatively just try 'string id' as another param in your Put method and see if that helps.

You also might need to put FromBody or FromUri Attributes on the each of the arguments in this case though.